# Chrome ignoring list-style and padding in style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm trying to add some very basic css to a list on a wordpress page where I remove the bullets and add a little padding between each list item. The list is generated by shortcode from a plugin called List-category-posts. The css works as expected on a Mac in Safari and Firefox but not Chrome.

https://annamaltz.com/writings/

```
.lcp_catlist li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

When I inspect the page in Chrome, I can see that its pulling from the parent theme's style.css file but not seeing my adjustments in the child's file.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome

Comment: I'm using Chrome on a Mac and have checked two different machines and have the same results: no padding between list items and bullets are visible. Potentially, it may not be an issue on Chrome on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Looks correct in Chrome (Win10). Try using the [Empty cache and hard reload](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/hard-reload) feature - your browser might be caching an old version of the style sheet.

Comment: Thanks ty2k! So weird that it was also happening on another Mac as well. Both machines must have been caching old style sheets. School boy error on my part. Grateful for your time. Cheers.

Comment: To avoid caching issues when I'm developing, I display the Chrome Developer tools, and turn off caching (via Preferences -> Network). I find this to be easier and more reliable than adding version strings everywhere, or trying to remember to do a manual reset of the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one machine, the Empty cache and hard reload feature in Chrome reset the cached style sheet. The other machine needed to have the ~/library/Google/Chrome dumped to correct the issue.

Thanks to ty2k for the answer and j08691 for having a look.